# Change the content for each tab Angular 2

Tags: html, typescript, angular, nativescript

I'm using SegmentedBar for tabs. And my *menu.html* file looks like this:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" width="310" height="610">
  <nav>
  <h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>
  <SegmentedBar #tabs [items]="items" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" ></SegmentedBar>
  </nav>
</StackLayout>
```

1. The problem is even if I modify it, nothing seems to happen on UI. It only shows the tabs, that's it, i.e. 'Hello World' doesn't show up on the interface. I want to modify my html, so there are other actions will happen. Why is that happening?
2. How can I change views, so that there are different views for each
   tab?

And here is my *menu.component.ts* file:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Page} from 'ui/page';
import {SegmentedBar, SegmentedBarItem, SelectedIndexChangedEventData} from 'ui/segmented-bar';

@Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
    templateUrl:"./components/menu/menu.html" 
})

export class TabsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
    selectedIndex: number;
    items: Array<any>;

    @ViewChild("tabs") tabs: ElementRef; // equal to getViewById() in NativeScript core

    constructor(private page: Page) {
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
        this.items = [{ title: 'Home' }, { title: 'G+' }, { title: 'Sync' }];
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.tabs.nativeElement.on(SegmentedBar.selectedIndexChangedEvent, (args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) => {
            switch (args.newIndex) {
                case 0:
                    console.log('Home selected')
                    break;
                case 1:
                    console.log('G+ selected')
                    break;
                case 3:
                    console.log('Sync selected')
                    break;
            }
        })
    }
    ngOnDestroy() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use DOM in NativeScript meaning you can not use browser specific tags like h1, ul, li, div, etc.. If you want your own tags you can achieve that with [integrating third-party components](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ui-with-xml#custom-components).

The Segmented Bar is different from the TabView - it does not provide you with a content space but only with a segmented bar. What you should do is to use the **selectedIndex** to modify your page depending on it.

Here is a very simple implementation on how to change the content based on the user selection (it is only for demonstration- there are many much better solutions. For example use partial views a.k.a. custom components and declare a boolean variable for the visibility change)

***app.component.html***

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" width="310" height="610">
  <SegmentedBar #tabs [items]="items" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" ></SegmentedBar>

  <GridLayout #firstTabContent width="300" height="500" backgroundColor="orange" fontSize="40">
        <Label text="FIRST" textWrap="true"></Label>
  </GridLayout>

  <GridLayout #secondTabContent width="300" height="500" backgroundColor="red" fontSize="40">
        <Label text="SECOND" textWrap="true"></Label>
  </GridLayout>

  <GridLayout #thirdTabContent width="300" height="500" backgroundColor="green" fontSize="40">
        <Label text="THIRD" textWrap="true"></Label>
  </GridLayout>   

</StackLayout>
```

***app.component.ts***

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

import {Page} from 'ui/page';
import {SegmentedBar, SegmentedBarItem, SelectedIndexChangedEventData} from 'ui/segmented-bar';

@Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
    selectedIndex: number;
    items: Array<any>;

    messages: Array<any>;

    @ViewChild("tabs") tabs: ElementRef;

    @ViewChild("firstTabContent") firstTabContent: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("secondTabContent") secondTabContent: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("thirdTabContent") thirdTabContent: ElementRef;

    constructor(private page: Page) {
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
        this.items = [{ title: 'First' }, { title: 'Second'},  { title: 'Third'}];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // the initial load setup
        this.firstTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "visible";
        this.secondTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "collapsed";
        this.thirdTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "collapsed";
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.tabs.nativeElement.on(SegmentedBar.selectedIndexChangedEvent, (args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) => {
            switch (args.newIndex) {
                case 0:
                    console.log('first selected');

                    this.firstTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "visible";
                    this.secondTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "collapsed";
                    this.thirdTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "collapsed";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    console.log('second selected')

                    this.firstTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "collapsed";
                    this.secondTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "visible";
                    this.thirdTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "collapsed";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    console.log('third selected')

                    this.firstTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "collapsed";
                    this.secondTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "collapsed";
                    this.thirdTabContent.nativeElement.visibility = "visible";
                    break;
            }
        })
    }

    ngOnDestroy() { }
}
```